# BytesIOhas data with getvalue but not read

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I have the following

```
block_blob_service = BlobServiceClient(account, sas)
container_client = block_blob_service.get_container_client(containerName)
downloader = container_client.download_blob(filename)
output_stream = io.BytesIO()
downloader.download_to_stream(output_stream)
contents = io.TextIOWrapper(output_stream, encoding='UTF-8')
print(len(output_stream.read(100))) 
print(len(contents.read(100))) 
print(len(output_stream.getvalue()))
```

This prints

```
[2021-03-12T05:24:46.043Z] 0
[2021-03-12T05:24:46.045Z] 0
[2021-03-12T05:24:46.048Z] 528672
```

I don't understand how this can happen – how am I supposed to use TextIOWrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try by resetting the stream's position to `0` and it should work. So your code would be:

```
block_blob_service = BlobServiceClient(account, sas)
container_client = block_blob_service.get_container_client(containerName)
downloader = container_client.download_blob(filename)
output_stream = io.BytesIO()
downloader.download_to_stream(output_stream)
contents = io.TextIOWrapper(output_stream, encoding='UTF-8')
output_stream.seek(0)
print(len(output_stream.read(100))) 
contents.seek(0)
print(len(contents.read(100))) 
print(len(output_stream.getvalue()))
```

The output will be

```
100
100
528672
```